# How do I obtain specific values from a data file containing a row of different values using an input validation loop?

Tags: arrays, c, file, scanf

I want to take a row of different values on a data file, and after reading the first few values separately, read every subsequent value afterwards using a for loop. It doesn't seem like the program is reading each subsequent value however, and displays nothing. How should I go about fixing this?

Let's say the values look like this:

```
4.2 2.0 8.0 3.4 5.1 8.9 7.9
```

This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main (void)
{
    int i=0,count;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("datafile.data","r");
    fscanf(ptr,"%d ",&count);
    double arr[count];
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)
    {
        fscanf(ptr,"%lf ",&arr[i]);
        printf("%lf\n",arr[i]);
    }
    fclose (ptr);
    return(0);
}
```

EDIT: There's supposed to be a 5 at the beginning for the %d so the row would look like 5 4.2 2.0 8.0 3.4 5.1 8.9 7.9

Comment: Are you sure about `fscanf(ptr,"%d ",&count);`? That doesn't match the input you show.

Comment: You also have not kind of error checking. For example, what happens if you fail to open the file? And always check what `fscanf` (or any `scanf` related function) [*returns*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value).

Comment: I'd read the entire line and then process it to extract what you want. https://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html

Comment: I believe I missed something. There was supposed to be "5 " before all of the values listed on the data file, and count is supposed to be for that integer, and scan the 5 values at the end of the row, while skipping 4.2 and 2.0. My bad.

Comment: Directly after the call to `fopen` add `if (!ptr) { perror("Could not open file"); return 1; }` What happens then?

Comment: By the way, there's really no need for an array with the code you show.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed some errors in your code, first is checking if the file exists and I changed the extension of the file to `.txt` second I read the values from the file as shown below.

```c
#include <stdio.h>


int main (void)
{
    int i=0,count;
    FILE *ptr;
    ptr = fopen("datafile.txt","r");

    if (ptr == NULL) // check if file exists
    {
        printf("Error!");
        return 1;
    }

    double buffer[20];


    while (fscanf(ptr, "%lf", &buffer[i]) == 1) // read file contents till end of file
    {
        printf("%.2lf\n", buffer[i]);
        i++;
    }


    return(0);
}
```

**Output**

```
4.20
2.00
8.00
3.40
5.10
8.90
7.90
```

Comment: Don't compare the result of `fscanf` with `EOF`, that will lead to an infinite loop if there's non-numeric input. Use `fscanf(...) == 1` as condition instead.

Answer (score 0):

Given an input file of

```
5
4.2 2.0 8.0 3.4 5.1 8.9 7.9
```

the first thing to do is ensure the file was [opened correctly](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen).

```
FILE *file = fopen("datafile.data", "r");

if (!file) {
    perror("fopen");
    exit(1);
}
```

The second thing you must do is ensure that the initial value was read correctly, and is in an appropriate range as to not cause [Undefined Behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) when creating the [VLA](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array#Variable-length_arrays). That means greater than zero, and below some reasonable limit as to not overflow your program's [*stack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-based_memory_allocation) (i.e., `ulimit -s`, etc.).

The [return value](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf#Return_value) of `fscanf` should always be checked to be the *expected number of successful conversions*. Here we are converting *one* value.

```
#define MAXSIZE 128

size_t size = 0;

if (1 != fscanf(file, "%zu", &size) || !size || size > MAXSIZE) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Invalid size.\n");
    return 1;
}
```

*([`size_t`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/size_t) is the most generally appropriate type to use for memory sizes and offsets.)*

---

Now, the comment above

> [ ... ] and scan the 5 values at the *end of the row*, while skipping 4.2 and 2.0.

introduces a problem:

Unless your input is always of a static size, how do we know how many values to skip?

If the stream is seekable, one way would be to simply read and count how many values there are. Subtracting the initial value from this count gives you the amount to skip. Afterwards, *rewind* the file and do the proper read & store pass on it.

Another option would be to only store the most recent *N* values read, discarding earlier values. This can be achieved with a type of circular buffer / queue.

A basic example:

```
double data[size];
size_t total_read = 0;
size_t index = 0;

while (1 == fscanf(file, "%lf", data + index)) {
    total_read++;
    index = (index + 1) % size;
}

if (total_read < size)
    fprintf(stderr, "WARN: Did not read all [%zu] values.\n", size);
```

Afterwards, if needed (i.e., order matters and `total_read > size`), the values can be return to their read order by *rotating* the buffer around `index`.